# Getting an error when trying Container App tutorial from Microsoft

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Given:
Windows 11

I'm trying to do the following tutorial but I'm getting an error as shown below when I try to `Build image in Azure` option

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/deploy-visual-studio-code

[image]